# What is the difference between border-box and content-box in CSS?

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between border-box and content-box in CSS?
I am not clearly understand between these two boxes. For example,
 `box-sizing:border-box;` and `box-sizing:content-box;`
The output of the two styles look similar.

Comment: It only affects the results of the `width` and `height` properties, and then there's a difference only if you have padding or a border.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-sizing

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing?v=example should answer your question.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-sizing

Comment: ... and with all the non-official links, here is the official W3C one: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#box-sizing

Answer (score 40, accepted):

While *box-sizing*: *border-box*; uses the box-model that people have come to associate with Internet Explorer, where the dimensions of the padding and border are included in the element’s dimensions.
[image]
<sup>(image [source](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/box-sizing-border-box-explained))</sup>

Example:

[image]
<sup>(image [source](https://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2013-11-17-box-model-behaviour/))</sup>

Demo Added.

```js
$("#content").on("click", function() {
  $("*").css("box-sizing", $(this).text());
});

$("#border").on("click", function() {
  $("*").css("box-sizing", $(this).text());
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #E18728;
  float: left;
}

.child {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 20%;
  border: 4px solid black;
  margin: .5em auto;
}

.twins {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 4px solid black;
  float: left;
}


/* styling for Pen, not related to box-sizing or layout */

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.buttons {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

p:not(.intro) {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <p class="intro">Click the <code>border-box</code> button to fix the layout with the power of Box Sizing!</p>
  <button id="content">content-box</button>
  <button id="border">border-box</button>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <p>Parent div with 50% width.</p>
  <div class="child">
    <p>Child div with 90% width, 4px black border, and 20% padding </p>
  </div>
  <div class="twins">
    <p>Child div with 50% width, 4px black border, and 1em padding</p>
  </div>
  <div class="twins">
    <p>Child div with 50% width, 4px black border, and 1em padding</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir!! I understood.

Comment: Glad you understood.

Comment: You have a wrong value in your image, it should not be `140px` on the right drawing (border-box), it should be `100px`, as it is on the left side

Comment: @LGSon u were right, i changed the images, this more clearer i hope.

Comment: after seeing this , it only takes me 10 sec to understand .

Answer (score 0):

You see the difference when you add border. `border:10px solid black` Let's say you have two boxes at the same dimension. And you want to add border to the blue one. If you have `box-sizing: content-box` (content-box is default), content area is "height" and "width". If you add border, content area will not change, border size will be added to the content area.

[image]

If you change it to `box-sizing: border-box`, you will have this:

[image]