# How to see the content-box, padding and border of HTML elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to create a CSS rule so I can easily distinguish between the content-box (white), the padding area (blue) and the border(green).

I know I can set a background-color and a border-color. But how to distinguish between content-box and padding area?

[image]

```css
#div1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
 
    
  padding: 40px;
  border: 10px solid green;
  
  background-color: lightblue;

}
```

```html
<div id="div1">I am a DIV with some content...</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Use this to color the _content-box_: `background-image: linear-gradient(red,red);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-origin: content-box;
`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453514/7935970 Please refer above URL Hope this helps.. 

Comment: in fact, you can't fill the padding with a background color, but there is a trick if you want to see the difference
http://jsbin.com/epezip/3/edit?html,css,output