# Why does the browser calculate px values unevenly?

Tags: html, css

I have a component that essentially displays a block centered within another block. But I've found that, even when using exact, non-decimal px values, the elements seem to render oddly as if the browser is calculating the values unevenly. Here is a simplified example:

```css
.outer-box {
  width: 28px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  background: blue;
}

.inner-box {
  width: 24px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-box">
  <div class="inner-box" />
</div>
```

So if I've worked this out right, there should be 2px of the outer-box to the left and right of the inner-box. However, instead the edges look uneven, and furthermore if I move the entire thing across the x axis, 1 px at a time, the 2px 'border' appears to jump in width each time it is moved.

I get the same issue on Chrome, FireFox and Edge.

Comment: `<div>` elements have a default value for `box-sizing` of `content-box` which won't include padding in the width allocation, you need to change it to `box-sizing: border-box;` to account for it. Hope the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453391/what-is-the-difference-between-border-box-and-content-box-in-css) can help you understand more.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening because you have given `width` to the `inner-box`. The remaining space in the div gives the feel of uneven padding. If you want to center align the div that looks equal on both sides; use `flex`. Your new css will be as follows:

```
.outer-box {
    width: 28px;
    padding: 0 2px;
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Everything else will remain same.

Answer (score 0):

See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-model).

Content `width` does not include `padding` by default.

[image: The box model]

So you have, from left to right:

1. Edge of the outer-box
2. 2px of left padding on the outer-box
3. Start of the inner-box
4. 24px of content width of the inner-box
5. 4px of content width of the outer-box that isn't filled by the inner-box
6. 2px of right padding on the outer-box

You can change that by leaving the inner-box as `width: auto` so it fills up all the available horizontal space in the `outer-box`.

```css
.outer-box {
  width: 24px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  background: blue;
}

.inner-box {
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-box">
  <div class="inner-box" />
</div>
```

You could also use [the `box-sizing` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to include the padding in the width calculation.

```css
.outer-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 28px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  background: blue;
}

.inner-box {
  width: 24px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-box">
  <div class="inner-box" />
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include, but I actually have a global style applying `border-box` so as far as I can tell the inner-box should be centered by the padding.

Comment: @ChrisKeogh — As this answer demonstrates, it is.

Comment: After doing a bit more digging, it looks like the issue is due to the device pixel ratio being a decimal. So the browser is rounding to the nearest whole pixel value. Thanks for your help all the same!